# show hello world swing with jni

Tags: c++, swing, qt, java-native-interface

This is my main.cpp code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <QDebug>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;
    jstring jstr;
    jobjectArray args;
    jclass stringClass;

    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options[3];

    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.compiler=NONE";
    options[1].optionString = "-Djava.classpath=.";
    options[2].optionString = "";

    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 3;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;

    jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    if (res < 0) {
        qDebug()<<"Can't create Java VM\n";
        exit(1);
    };
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("HelloWorldSwing");
    if (cls == 0) qDebug()<<"Sorry, I can't find the class";
    jmethodID get_main_id =
    env->GetStaticMethodID(cls,"main","([Ljava/lang/String;)V");

    jstr=env->NewStringUTF("hola que tal");
    stringClass=env->FindClass("java/lang/String");
    args=env->NewObjectArray(1,stringClass,jstr);

    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls,get_main_id,args);

    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
    qDebug()<<"Java VM destroy\n";

}//end main.
```

HelloWorldSwing is a class that show a jframe with "Hello world" text, but don't show nothing, if i write system.out.println("hello world")in the java class, function correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You're destroying the VM before it has a chance to display the UI.

The call to System.out.println is synchronous, so it happens before you destroy the VM.

Creating a UI involves creating and dispatching events on a separate thread.  If you were to simply pause for several seconds before destroying the VM, I think you'd see your UI show up.

Comment: I have try to add a sleep function before destroy the jvm, i use this code: 
    `env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls,get_main_id,args);
    I::sleep(5);
    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();`
wait five seconds before destroy the jvm, but not show the ui.

Comment: What platform are you on?  Different platforms may have different requirements with respect to threading and starting up the event dispatch thread.

Comment: For example, [`simpleJavaLauncher`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#/legacy/mac/library/samplecode/simpleJavaLauncher/Introduction/Intro.html) on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the main class of java.
JNI calls the main method and when this end, the program end. I just put a `guithread.join ();` in the main method and all run correctly.